# How can I get access to Introductory Overlay?

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

I would like to customize introductory overlay in my iOS app with appearance() method, but I can't find a class responsible for this overlay in API. Do anyone know how can I get an access to introductory overlay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We currently don't expose the introductory overlay UI class so you can change the appearance. We have raised this with our engineering team.

Answer (score 0):

Cast SDK v3 for iOS introduced [GCKUIStyle](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_styles#style_hierarchy).
This allows you to customize appearance of all Cast Views without having a reference to any. As it contains pretty much all properties for customization.

For [Introductory Overlay](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist/cast-button#prompting) specifically

```
GCKUIStyle *castStyle = [GCKUIStyle sharedInstance];

// customize Introductory Overlay
GCKUIStyleAttributesInstructions *instructionsCtrlStyle = [[castStyle castViews] instructions];
[instructionsCtrlStyle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
[instructionsCtrlStyle setButtonTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[castStyle applyStyle];
```