# How to style GCKUIMiniMediaControlsViewController in iOS?

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

I'm upgrading current Cast SDK to V3 and want to use build-in UI components and remove deprecated functions.

Currently, the `GCKUIMiniMediaControlsViewController` has a white/light theme but I'd like to change it to a darker theme. However, I couldn't find any function/propert/protocol that I can use to change the style. The document [Add Advanced Cast v3 Features to your iOS App](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_advanced#how_volume_control_works) says:

> The Cast framework widgets supports the Apple UIAppearance Protocol in
>   UIKit to change the appearance of the widgets across your app, such as
>   the position or border of a button. Use this protocol to style the
>   Cast framework widgets to match an existing apps styling.

This makes me feel like I can change the appearance but I'm not quite sure what does *The Cast framework widgets supports the Apple UIAppearance Protocol in UIKit* mean :(

I also find a previous question which also related to Cast SDK's UI component. [How can I get access to Introductory Overlay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874475/how-can-i-get-access-to-introductory-overlay)

Can anyone help me how to change the style for `GCKUIMiniMediaControlsViewController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow Apple's instructions on using the UIAppearance protocol. Note that any changes you make to the styling will happen across the entire app.

Answer (score 5):

Cast SDK v3 for iOS introduced [GCKUIStyle](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_styles#style_hierarchy).
This makes styling of all cast views very easy (which includes [mini controller](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist/sender#sender-mini-controller), [expanded controller](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist/sender#sender-control-elements), etc). As it contains pretty much all properties for customization.

For GCKUIMiniMediaControlsViewController specifically

```
GCKUIStyle *castStyle = [GCKUIStyle sharedInstance];

// customize Mini Controller
GCKUIStyleAttributesMiniController *miniCtrlStyle = [[[castStyle castViews] mediaControl] miniController];
[miniCtrlStyle setBackgroundColor:backColor];
[miniCtrlStyle setIconTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[miniCtrlStyle setHeadingTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[castStyle applyStyle];
```

Comment: I believe this should be the accepted answer, it uses the last SDK Version and it also helped me to find HeadingTextColor.

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiappearance

For example if you want to change the background color of every UILabel that is contained in GCKUIExpandedMediaControlsViewController.

ex in Swift:

> UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf:[GCKUIExpandedMediaControlsViewController.self]).backgroundColor = URColors.URStrawberryRed