# Customise GCKUIExpandedMediaControlsViewController , GCKUIMiniMediaControlsViewController and "Cast to" view?

Tags: ios, customization, chromecast, google-cast, uiappearance

I know already there is a question 
[How to style GCKUIMiniMediaControlsViewController in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905943/how-to-style-gckuiminimediacontrolsviewcontroller-in-ios)
and the answer says we can customise it using the UIAppearance protocol. But the view controllers have only conformed to UIAppearanceContainer protocol and I cannot access the titleLabel, subtitleLabel, etc in miniController to have different font and size. Also how can we access and customise the device selection view ("Cast to" view) ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Add Mini Controllers](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_integrate#add_mini_controllers), there are two ways to add the mini controller to a sender app:

> - Let the Cast framework manage the layout of the mini controller by wrapping your existing view controller with its own view controller.
>
>   **Note**: This approach is limited in that you cannot customize the animation and cannot configure the behavior of the container view controller.
> - Manage the layout of the mini controller widget yourself by adding it to your existing view controller by providing a subview in the storyboard.
>
>   **Note**: Add the mini controller directly to your existing view controller by using `createMiniMediaControlsViewController` to create a `GCKUIMiniMediaControlsViewController` instance and then adding it to the container view controller as a `subview`.

See [Style the Widgets](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_advanced#style_the_widgets) for how your sender app can configure the appearance of the widgets across your app.

You may want to also review the requirements and best practices in [Sender App](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist/sender#top_of_page).

Comment: The question is not about adding the controllers, but customising them in iOS. I had already gone through https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_advanced#style_the_widgets and you can see that it is not clear how to customise other elements except buttons.